# how to query different columns and stack into new table in google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, localization, google-query-language

Hi I have columns like so, where it's auto fill every rows.
Where column BCD is from source a, column EFG from source b and HIJ from source c

sheet data

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date | Name | Cost | Date | Name | Cost | Date | Name | Cost |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | Alan | 5 | 2022-01-03 | James | 6 | 2022-01-02 | Timmy | 5 |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 | Hana | 5 | 2022-01-03 | Paul | 6 | 2022-01-02 | Jane | 5 |

into
summary sheet

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date | Name | Cost | Source |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | Alan | 5 | sourceA |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 | Hana | 5 | sourceA |
| 4 | 2022-01-03 | James | 6 | sourceB |
| 5 | 2022-01-03 | Paul | 6 | sourceB |
| 6 | 2022-01-02 | Timmy | 5 | sourceC |
| 7 | 2022-01-02 | Jane | 5 | sourceC |

How do I achieve this with formula query, stacking it on top one another.
Source is using if but then how do you detect last row and used it for the if.

- the rows for each source might be different.

Comment: How many sources across the sheet sideways?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What formula are you using in the "Source" column? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is array: `{}` inside of it you can use comma `,` to put something next to each other or semicolon `;` to put something under something else. eg. having:

```
={1,2;3,4}
```

will yield:

```
     A       B
   ------+-------+
1 |  1   |   2
   ------+-------+
2 |  3   |   4
```

in that manner you can do:

```
={QUERY(B:D);
  QUERY(E:G);
  QUERY(H:J)}
```

side note: if your locale is non-english then comma `,` in array is replaced by backslash `\`

Comment: hi when i tried to do query(B3:D); query(E3:G) it only shows B:D, whereas when I state as query(B2:D5);query(E2:D8) it combines both. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: @Hal yes. your E3:G query is there but under empty rows of 1st query. therefore try it like this: `=QUERY({QUERY(B3:D); QUERY(E3:G)}, "where Col1 is not null", )`

Comment: oh got it, I tried using an array formula ArrayFormula(MAX((F:F<>"")*(ROW(F:F)))) to get last row and do an indirect referencing instead. However the above solution is great.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array notation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en-GB) to combine the ranges, and combine them with either `filter()` or `query()` to remove the empty rows.

[Filter docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

[Query docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)